# How to pass Xml file using RestClient in Post - C#?

Tags: c#, api, post, restsharp, rest-client

I'm trying to pass xml file to api using RestSharp, but I'm receiving the file at the Post method as null.

Here is my code:

```
 public void SendXmlToApi()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(_uri);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddFile("Xml",XmlPath);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/xml");
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        bool res = (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

And my Post Func:

```
   [HttpPost]
    [Route("Test")]
    public void UpdateResult(XDocument a)
    {

        
    }
```

Any idea whats the problem?

Comment: Did you try adding `[FromBody]` before your `XDocument a`?

Comment: yes, didn't help:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use XML, so this deviates a little from your example, but it is a viable option for posting XML into a [HttpPost] API endpoint. I used your `SendXmlToApi()` example untouched (just supplied my own `_uri` and `XmpPath` variables) and was successful (Core 3.1).

I modified your receiving code to be:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test")]
public async Task UpdateResult()
{
    string body = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(body);
}
```

Of course, you'll want to put guard rails on this and have proper error handling and validation, but it should get you over the hump.